# MATLAB GUI - Accessor method or property edit? What's best practice?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I'm learning how to program MATLAB GUI's and am using GUIDE. I'm curious what is considered better practice: using the MATLAB 'set( )' function to edit an objects property, or simply the dot operator to edit the objects property.

Say for example I had an editable text box. The tag of this text box is 'string_fs'. There are two ways that I've found to change the string of this object:

```
handles.string_fs.String = 'hello';
```

or

```
set(handles.string_fs, 'String', 'hello');
```

Is there any benefit of one method vs the other?

Comment: For the sake of readability I prefer the dot notation for single property access and `set`/`get` for multiple properties. On the other hand if I need to consider backward compatibility,  `set`/`get` is the way to go as dot notation was first slowly added in `2014b`.

Comment: There might be _very tiny_ performance difference, but in general I would follow @Skogsv advice: Just make your choice between readability and backward code compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mainly a personal preference *unless* you need to write code which will work in pre-HG2 versions of MATLAB (before R2014b) in which case you would need to use `set` and `get` to maintain  backwards compatibility.

Here are a few other advantages to using `set` and `get` methods:

**Manipulation of Multiple Objects Simultaneously**

You can have an array of objects or handles and change a property on all of them simultaneously

```
ax(1) = subplot(1,2,1);
ax(2) = subplot(1,2,2);

% Change the font weight of both axes object to be the same
set(ax, 'FontWeight', 'bold')

% Change the font weight to be different for each
set(ax, {'FontWeight'}, {'bold'; 'normal'})
```

You can do something similar with dot notation but I think it's a little less readable

```
[ax.FontWeight] = deal('bold');
```

**Changing Multiple Properties Simultaneously**

You can, in one statement, change the values of multiple properties which I think can help with readability and keep your code concise.

```
set(ax, 'FontSize', 20, 'FontWeight', 'bold', 'FontName', 'arial')
```

As pointed out in the comments by @Hoki, this is particularly important if you are updating properties that are inter-dependent. For example modifying the `XData` and `YData` of a plot where they both need to be the same size.

So this:

```
hplot = plot(1, 1);
set(hplot, 'XData', rand(10, 1), 'YData', rand(10, 1))
```

Instead of this:

```
hplot = plot(1, 1);

set(hplot, 'XData', rand(10, 1))
% Plot won't render here

set(hplot, 'YData', rand(10, 1))
% Plot will be able to render
```

**Programmatically Get Possible Values**

With dot notation, you can use tab completion to get a list of possible values; however, you can do this programmatically with `set` by simply not providing a value.

```
possible = set(axes, 'FontWeight')

%   'normal'
%   'bold'
```

**Shortened and Case-Insensitive Properties**

I don't recommend using these next two, but they are possible with `set` and `get`.

With the `set` and `get` methods you don't have to provide an *entire* properties name, just enough letters that it's unique.

```
set(ax, 'FontW', 'bold')
```

Also when using `set` and `get`, the property name is case insensitive

```
set(ax, 'fontweight', 'bold')
```

Comment: another example where you _have_ to use `set` is when you need to change **multiple properties in the same instruction** (otherwise Matlab can throw a fit). For example, this can happen often when changing `FaceColor` property of a graphic object from `'flat'` to `'interp'` (if you don't also assign simultaneously the `FaceVertexCData` property, Matlab throw a warning and stop rendering). A common occurrence is also if you want to change the `min`, `max` and/or current `value` of a slider (if the new `max` conflict with the old `min`), etc ...

Comment: Ha ha ... I went for some complicated examples to illustrate it and you put the most common reason (which is the biggest reason I use `set` too). Well done!